# How to make an automatic installation ISO image based on ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso

Tags: boot, system-installation, iso, automatic

I'm working on making the installation of Ubuntu automatic and without any keystrokes in Dell PowerEdge R640.

Attached [ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/bionic/ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso), then rebooted, and the installation started, but in the following process, there are a lot of steps which need manual keystrokes.

For example, the first pop up window:

```
Try Ubuntu without installing,
Install Ubuntu,
OEM install (for manufactures),
Check disc for defects.
```

[image: interface]

I just want to select the first option and don't want press any key. I guess I should make some changes based on the original ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso.

So the key points are:

- How to make such an ISO which support automatically installation?
- Which files need changes?

Answer (score 3):

This scenario of yours is covered in the Ubuntu installation guide.

Read the section [Automatic Installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/18.04/installation-guide/amd64/ch04s06.html) for how to go about achieving that. Next, you can choose from either of the two methods described to do that.

Lastly, there is another option to automate it even more. Use the net boot iso to automate the disk inserting part. Just boot up the PC/image without any other boot media, and set up the PXE/dhcp/tft server and you are mostly done.

Lastly about the grub choice. If you remaster the image, you can put a grub config with default pre selected option and a default timeout.
I think the default installation image already supports that.